# pry not available in the irb debugger

Tags: ruby, debugging, pry

I want to use pry from within irb/debugger, so I can:

- invoke step, next, continue, finish inside of pry
- still be able to set breakpoints, etc.

What I did is the following:

```
$ gem install pry
$ gem install debugger
$ gem install debugger-pry
```

In the code I have inserted `require 'debugger'; debugger`

Then I start my program with `ruby example`, the irb promp starts and as described [here](https://github.com/pry/debugger-pry) it should display the pry command on `help`, but it does not.

```
ruby-debug help v1.5.0
...
(rdb:1) pry
*** Unknown command: "pry".  Try "help".
```

Any idea how I could check whether it is installed correctly or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
require 'debugger/pry'
```

you could add it to the top of your example.rb file.